# CSS hover effect not covering all images in full

Tags: html, css

On my WordPress category pages I have a number of the articles and their thumbnails displayed, with an effect to show a dark overlay when hovered over, but if the images are a little larger than most, the overlay breaks a little and shows a gap. I've provided a link, hover over the last 2 to test with.

*ALSO, the a href="#" link is only clickable on the icon that appears, not the whole image which I would prefer. I am refering to the first a href which covers the entire div.

[image]

http://bit.ly/1wtnY3d

```
<a href="#">
<div class="category-article-thumbnail">
    <div class="view third-effect">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="mask">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="info" title="View Article"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-label"><?php single_cat_title( '', true ); ?></div>
        <!-- <i class="category-label-end"></i> -->
    </div>
</div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
    /** CSS3 Hover Effects **/

.view {
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: default;
   max-height: 227px;
}

.view .mask {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   overflow: hidden;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}

.view img {
   display: block;
   position: relative;
}

.view a.info {
   background:url('http://highways.designlocker.co.uk/wp-content/themes/highways/images/article-click-icon3.png') center no-repeat;
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding:0;
   text-indent:-9999px;
   width:60px;
   height:52px;
}

.third-effect .mask {
   opacity: 0;
   overflow:visible;
   border:100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
   box-sizing:border-box;
   transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.third-effect a.info {
   position:relative;
   top:-30px; /* Center the link */
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity 0.5s 0s ease-in-out;
}

.third-effect:hover .mask {
   opacity: 1;
   border:100px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.third-effect:hover a.info {
   opacity:1;
   transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

/** end CSS3 Hover Effects **/
```

Comment: I think this 
`.third-effect:hover .mask {
   opacity: 1;
   border:200px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}`
will resolve an issue. just make a border thicker

Comment: @JordanC26 if possible share a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code

Comment: @Banzay made things worse and some weird effects happen with that added.

Answer (score 0):

You have nested `a` tags which is invalid HTML.

You need to fix your html, because the browser is rendering the html differently than what you think, in order to fix the invalid html.

Comment: Even with it deleted it's the same. I am working on switching things to the top a tag instead containing the whole div, but temporarily evern with it deleted it's the same.

Comment: @JordanC26 yes but we cannot help fix anything if the html is invalid. And nested `a` tags is one of the few mistakes that will truly make the browser render wrong things. AS for the cursor not showing correct, the `.view` class has a `cursor:default` which remove the link pointer..